# Swift rounding to X decimals places issue when .999999

Tags: ios, switch-statement, rounding, precision

I did try different rounding to decimal places methods and all of them have the same in common. When I use a number, lets say 0.99999 and I want to round it to 2 decimal places. My expected result would be 0.99 but instead I get 1.00

I did try

```
let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(decimals))
let roundedVal = round(value * divisor) / divisor
```

Also did try

```
String(format:"%.2f",decimals)
```

And

```
let behavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: decimals, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)

NSDecimalNumber(value: value).rounding(accordingToBehavior: behavior)

let roundedValue2 = NSDecimalNumber(value: 0.6849).rounding(accordingToBehavior: behavior)
```

All methods give me the same issue.
Some ideas?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: 
The idea is that rounding is okay for all cases but not okay for that 0.9999 case. The display numbers are small always (range from 0.000 to 1) and decimals to show is parameter so 0.348 should be 0.35 and not 0.34 (when trunked)

Answer (score 2):

```
let amount = 0.99999999999999

let formatter = NumberFormatter()

formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

formatter.roundingMode = .floor // rounding mode floor is the key here

let formattedAmount = formatter.string(from: amount as NSNumber)!

print(formattedAmount) // 0.99
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Works well for the case of 0.9999 but cos is trunking the cases like 0.3499 will be just 0.34 and should be 0.35. Thanks I did edit my question to add that extra information, sorry if wasn't clear enough.

Comment: How can you expect 0.349 to become 0.35 when you want 0.999 not to become 1.0 ?

Comment: You say you want 0.99999 rounded to 2 decimal places and expect the result to be 0.99.  That is not rounding.  The correct resulting rounding SHOULD be 1.0.  Are you wanting a special case for 0.99999?